# Python Selenium: How to get elements from multiple html lists of undefined length that have the same relative xpath?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am scraping a page where I am looking for all elements inside the following lists:

```
description = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'list') and h1/text()='Values']/ul[@class='bullet-list']")
```

But there is an unknown number of them on a given page, mostly between 3-10. There is also an unknown number of items in each list (the # of items in each list do not match). If I search for the list items as such:

```
description = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'list') and h1/text()='Values']/ul[@class='bullet-list']/li")
```

I get all the list items but now I dont know which list they belonged to.

What I want to do is something like this

```
description = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'list') and h1/text()='Values']/ul[@class='bullet-list']")
for x in range(len(description)):
    values = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"{description[x].xpath}/li")
    for y in values:
        b_list.append(y.text)
    a_list.append(b_list)
```

So you can see why I need to know which list the items are coming from so they can be inside the same [].

I can use absolute xpath to solve this but its better if I can find a way with relative xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get items from multiple lists you can try

```
lists = []
description = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'list') and h1='Values']/ul[@class='bullet-list']")
for _list in description:
    lists.append([li.text for li in _list.find_elements(By.XPATH, './li')])
print(lists)
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I had tried the same solution before but for the xpath I used '/li' instead of './li', which didnt yield anything, and so I thought this solution didnt work. thanks!